# How to linearize inequalities having max or min?

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

I'm modeling an LP problem in which I have to maximize an objective function. Two of the constraints are the following, where $k_i$ are constants and $x_i$ decision variables (continuous). Could anyone help me on how to linearize these constraints?
\begin{align}
\text{max}{[(x_1 + k_1), (x_2 + x_3 + x_4)]} &\leq k_2\\
\text{min}{[(x_1 + k_1), (x_2 + x_3 + x_4)]} &\geq -k_2
\end{align}

Answer (score 8):

$\max(y,z)\le b$ is equivalent to
\begin{align}
y&\le b\\
z&\le b
\end{align}
The $\min$ constraint is similar.